# Context free grammar of $L = \{w \in \{a, b, c\}^* : |w|_{c} = 3k +1 \}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

So, this is my first homework in conext free grammar, I want the grammar that generates all possible words in L, I have come out with the following rules
$$
S \rightarrow aS | bS| cX\\
X \rightarrow aX| bX| cY\\
Y \rightarrow aY|bY|cZ|cS\\
Z \rightarrow aZ|bZ |cK\\
K \rightarrow aK| bK| a| b| \epsilon
$$

but it does not generate words of for wc where c is not in w.

Comment: To clarify, $L$ is the set of strings $w$ of $a, b, c$ so that the number of times $c$ appears is $1$ modulo $3$?

Comment: yes that the set of words in L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, but as you say, you're missing the case where $c$ is at the end of the word. Moreover, no word generated by your grammar has less than $4$ $c$'s in it, i.e. you're missing the case where $|w|_c = 1$.

I think the problem is that you have too many states. You just need the three states for the number of $c$'s modulo $3$. You start in $S$ can be $0$ mod $3$, $X$ can be $1$ mod $3$, and $Y$ can be $2$ mod $3$. You move between these states by adding another $c$, stay in the states by adding $a$ or $b$, and you can only terminate from state $X$. That is, I suggest:

\begin{align*}
S &\to aS \mid bS \mid cX \\
X &\to aX \mid bX \mid cY \mid \varepsilon \\
Y &\to aY \mid bY \mid cS.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any resources, so I can learn more about grammars

Comment: @ahmedben I don't, I'm sorry. This is just from memory from my undergrad.